# Resource Route with parameter

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-6

I have resource route like this

```
Route::resource('chapter', 'ChapterController');
```

I want to pass parameter id to it like this

```
Route::resource('chapter/{id}', 'ChapterController');
```

and use it in my controller like this

```
public function index($id)
    {
        $subject=Subject::find($id);
        $chapter=Chapter::where('subject_id',$id)->get();
        return view('chapter.index',[
            'subject'=>$subject,
            'chapter'=>$chapter
        ]);
    }
```

Please help me

Comment: what framework is it about?

Comment: @Capitaine Laravel.

Comment: Will you be passing the subject id to all of the methods in your `ChapterController` or just the `index()` method?

Comment: Laravel resource routes are shorthand for a specific set of routes seen [here](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/controllers#resource-controllers) if you want to override them you can specify a [partial resource route](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/controllers#restful-partial-resource-routes) and then define your resources manually.

Answer (score 1):

Route::resource which is called RESTful resource controller sets up default routes and handles the given below actions.

```
Verb          Path                                     Action                       Route Name

GET           /chapter                                 index                        chapter.index

GET           /chapter/create                          create                       chapter.create

POST          /chapter                                 store                        chapter.store

GET           /chapter/{id}                            show                         chapter.show

GET           /chapter/{id}/edit                       edit                         chapter.edit

PUT|PATCH     /chapter/{id}                            update                       chapter.update

DELETE        /chapter/{id}                            destroy                      chapter.destroy
```

> If you need to add additional routes to a resource controller beyond
>   the default set of resource routes, you should define those routes
>   before your call to Route::resource; otherwise, the routes defined by
>   the resource method may unintentionally take precedence over your
>   supplemental routes:

```
Route::post('chapter/{id}', 'ChapterController@method')->name('chapter.action');
//...
Route::resource('chapter', 'ChapterController');
```

Answer (score 0):

Your index function has to be with Request parameter also:
index(Request $request, $id)

Answer (score 0):

make  sure all methods of resource controller 
pass id to it

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `id` for your `index` method and already declared a `resource route` then you need to use custom `route`, because laravel `resource` `index` `route` doesn't support `id` or any other `parameter`

```
//your Resource Route
Route::resource('chapter', 'ChapterController');

//Custom `route` for your `index` method it will replace your `resource index route`
Route::get('chapter/{id}', ['as'=>'chapter.index','uses'=>'ChapterController@index']);
```